# Order dropdown list in ASP.Net mvc 5 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a dropdown and I want it to appear in a particular order where dropdown option `header` should come before `footer`. but I am not able to do so.

**Helper**

```
public static readonly string HEADER_ID = "-1000";
public static readonly string FOOTER_ID = "-1001";
```

**CSHTML**

```
<select id="simTextEditorSelection" onchange="ShowTextEditorBasedOnSelection();"  style="float:right;">
    @foreach (PageInfoMV anItemForEditor in Model.ItemContents)
    {
        <option value="@anItemForEditor.ItemId">@anItemForEditor.ItemDisplayText</option>
    }
```

**UI**

[image]

P.S: I don't want to change the enum values of Header and footer. Please guide me.

My Attempt:

```
@foreach (PageInfoMV anItemForEditor in Model.ItemContents.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id))
```

But it created some other issues. So, I want to avoid it.

Comment: Why negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Action` you can create a `SelectList` from any list as followed:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var list = db.MyClass.ToList(); //or an other way to get the list of items
    //you can add som more items to the list:
    list.Add(new MyClass { Id=-1000, Name="Some Name" });
    ViewBag.Selectlist = new SelectList(list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

In the `View`:

```
@{
    var optionList = ViewBag.Selectlist as SelectList;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.someProperty, optionlist, "- Select an option -")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your cshtml to this and you should have your wish

```
<select id="simTextEditorSelection" onchange="ShowTextEditorBasedOnSelection();"  style="float:right;">
@foreach (PageInfoMV anItemForEditor in Model.ItemContents.OrderByDescending())
{
    <option value="@anItemForEditor.ItemId">@anItemForEditor.ItemDisplayText</option>
}
```